# Access logging for scala application on http4s

Tags: scala, logging, logback, http4s

We have a rest microservice developed using scala http4s. For logging we are using logback.xml. We want to configure 'access logs', similar to how we have it for tomcat

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/tomcat-access-log-configuration-example/

We want to similarly log all requests - its method type, http status code, time etc, like below

```
"GET /v2/users?searchCriteria=name HTTP/1.1" 200 2333
```

Is there a way to do it for http4s? Any plugin/framework that can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I recommend also asking in the `#http4s` channel of the [**typelevel discord** server](https://discord.gg/a9gwu6U6).